# Localhost mongod server not starting after shutting down

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

I want to use mongod --auth command for authentication so I shutdown the mongod server using shell command that is:

```
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer();
```

Now when I try to start the server again, It won't start.

I'm using this command to start:

```
mongod --auth
```

I tried to change the port number

```
mongod --port 27018
```

But, nothing works...

It gives me the same error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.710+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}                                                                    {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.714+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}                                     {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.731+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}                                                                                                   {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.732+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}                                                                                                                                  {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.733+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}                                {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.734+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}                        {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.745+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":8240,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-ER92717"}}                             {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.746+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}                                                     {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.748+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.0-rc0","gitVersion":"9a324616c6557efc15ee6bf0c42587c0f475e573","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}                                                          {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.749+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19042)"}}}                                                         {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.751+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}                                                                                                     {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.763+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\\data\\db\\ not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}                                                                                                                                   {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.764+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}                                                                 {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.766+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}                                                                                                                       {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.767+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}                                                                                                              {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.773+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}                                                                                                            {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.775+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}                                                                                                              {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.776+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}                                                                                                             {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.778+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}                                                                                                    {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.780+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}                                                                                                                   {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.782+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}                                                                                                               {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.791+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}                                                                                                 {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.792+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}                                                                                                                   {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.794+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}                                                                                                                         {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.796+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}                                                                                                                           {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.797+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}                                                                                                                         {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.799+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}                                                                                                                {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.805+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}                                                                                                                 {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.807+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}                                                                                                                  {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.809+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}     {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-03T12:23:31.812+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

Comment: That's not an error, that is an informational message letting you know TLS1.0 has been disabled for security.

Comment: What are the versions of MongoDB and Operating System it is installed on?

Comment: Is this the only message you get? There should be more.